# Way to carry a wedding band on your person when it's not on your finger

Tags: clothing, safety, jewelry

I'm searching for ways to carry my wedding ring on my person when I want to remove it from my finger. (The band is an indestructible, smooth, wedding band.)

The difficulty is that the band has to stay with me, and not injure me, during extreme physical activity, soaked in sweat; running, inverted positions, swinging from hands, swimming and any other movement you can think of.

I'm looking for ideas that do not involve bags or backpacks of any type (including the "small personal items" belts that runners often use.)

The best I've come up with, is to tie it into the drawstring of my pants or bathing-suit. This has the slight drawback of requiring me to be aware when untieing the pants so as not to drop the ring.

Comment: I've found the perfect hack with a loop of necklace cord. I've posted it, but it's way at the bottom because it has no votes :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much tinkering, here is the best solution I could come up with.

Notably:
- there is no "hardware" to fiddle with, break or pull your hair
- no dexterity required, I can shift my ring to this while running
- cheap, low profile, wearable in shower/swimming, sweat-proof

Buy some 1mm (or 1.5mm, whatever you prefer) cotton, waxed necklace cord. Make a loop which, when doubled, can be comfortably negotiated over your head. Wear the plain, doubled loop. When you need to remove and carry your ring(s): Open the loop, pass a bight through the ring, and put your head through both bights...

[image]

Getting the length of the necklace just right requires some fiddling. Start with a long piece of string and tie just one of the two fisherman's knots. That way you have a very easily adjustable loop. Wear it both ways and find just the right length that the double-loop-no-ring fits easily over your head, but the double-loop-with-ring won't (for example) slip off your head in a handstand, swimming, whatever you're going to be doing.

Answer (score 7):

Get a very small S-biner. Attach it somewhere on your person, and attach your wedding band to the other side as needed.

Shown below is a picture of this on a belt loop, holding keys instead of a wedding band. This should be quite secure, especially with the "locking" S-biner shown. If all you have is a bathing suit drawstring, you can tie it on to half of the biner, and clip on the ring when needed.

[image]

Comment: this is a very good idea. Most of the clothing I wear doesn't have belt loops, but I can work around that by sewing in small loop or something. Bonus, this also allows me to carry a key.

Comment: I'm marking this accept d because it's the best idea that is different from what id already come up with. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, but I'm revoking the Accept as I've found the perfect hack which I've posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming you have a safe place already to store things like ID, credit cards, and cell phone, it seems like the sensible thing to do is to leave your ring there, perhaps in an inner pocket of your wallet.

Comment: there isn't really a truly save place to store things. Currently, I leave the ring (sometimes) in a bag (or whatever) I carry along. But there's always the risk someone will grab my bag (which contains important, but easily replacable stuff only) -- hate to lose my wedding band that way.

Answer (score 4):

wear a chain around your neck and slide the ring onto it.

Alternately, get a mini-clip and attach it to your house or car keys.

Comment: I've considered that... but it's a bit tedious to have to open the chain to thread the band on. The upshot is the chain can be short enough so as not to slip over my head.

Comment: @CraigConstantine With some searching you may be able to find a necklace chain that opens very easily & quickly, yet is 100% secure. There's also the option to keep an easy-open clasp or hook on that necklace chain at all times, and using it to attach the ring when you need to ... though I can't picture what that clasp would look like or how "fashionable" it would look without the ring on it.

Comment: This could work well if I use something non-metalic like a string/strand/strap  (but weak enough to break before choking me) and then only click a small S-biner (mentioned in another answer too) to it when I want to attach the band.

Answer (score 1):

The only viable option is to use (water resistant) tape. Wrap it around your arm and put the wedding band under it. It's even safer if you wrap it twice and put the band in between the two layers. This will probably work well but it's a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: Did you really mean "*only* viable option"? That seems a bit overstated.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Agreed! Wholeheartedly! This is, after all, a site about thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 0):

Get some lite climbing rope or parachute cord

[image]

You pass the rope loop through the ring the pass across the bottom and up the top side.
It is called a Lark's head (cow hitch).
[image]

And I would use fisherman knot on the rope.  I think that is what you are currently using.

Comment: this is not what I'm currently using. It is actually not secure also. I tried this, and it's quite trivial for the string to work its way off of plain bad. The pulled-over-loop works loose, and a couple good bounces and the ring is gone.

Comment: You tried it and it did not work so you down voted.  It was a good enough idea for you to try.  You really think this rises to "Not Useful".  There are other options.   I used to be a climber but I am not interesting in helping at this point.

Comment: By "I tried this," I meant I had tried this before posting my Q here. It not (by any stretch of the imagination) a secure way to attach a ring-shaped-anything to a bight and therefore I feel it's not a good idea.